# how to specify the length of char[] to be printed out in printf

Tags: c

Given a `char[]` in c, I want to specify the length of output from that array starting with some position in `printf`, how can I conveniently do that?

For example, I want to print the portion from position 3 (indexed from 0) to position 8:

```
printf("%s", char_array+3..char_array+8)
```

I could make a temporary char[] with the desired length, but that is not very convenient. Or I could write a substring function

```
char* substring(const char* str, size_t begin, size_t len) {
    if (str == 0 || strlen(str) == 0 || strlen(str) < begin || strlen(str) < (begin + len))
        return 0;
    return strndup(str + begin, len);
}
```

But if I call

```
printf("%s", substring(s, 3, 5));
```

I am afraid there will be memory leak.

What do you think about the best way to do this?

Comment: Yes, there will be a memory leak.

Comment: I would recommend against ever using `str[n]dup` because it has the insidious property of creating memory leaks without you ever seeing `malloc` anywhere

Comment: @Seth You'd prefer a `malloc` and then a `strcpy`? Better would be to choose a language that supported strings better.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes, because the `malloc` would let you know you needed a `free`, whereas `strndup` makes you break the rule of one `free` for every `malloc`. But yes, I also agree with your second sentence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int printmid(const char *data, size_t start, int len) {
  return printf("%.*s", len, data + start);
}

int main(void) {
  char data[] = "Hello, World!";
  printmid(data, 3, 6);
  puts("");
  return 0;
}
```

output

```
lo, Wo
```

Comment: The original was expressed in terms of the numbers 3 and 8; your answer is written in terms of the numbers 3 and 6.  I know how you derived 6 from 3 and 8, and it shouldn't take long for anyone to work it out.  So what you've got is OK, but (IMO) it is best to tackle the problem with the numbers the user gives, rather than derived numbers.  What you've got is, and essentially always was, correct; but it is/was not crystal clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
int end = 8;
int bgn = 3;
int len = end - bgn + 1;
printf("%*.*s", len, len, char_array + bgn);
```

Note that `len` should be an `int` (and not, for example, the difference between two pointers - that's a `ptrdiff_t` or `size_t`).  You can also omit the first length if you want - both can be specified, and they have specific meanings if the source string is shorter than the designated length (meaning there's a null byte in the string before `char_array + end`).  Clearly, if the string in `char_array` is shorter than 4 bytes, then what follows the terminating null is probably garbage, and GIGO applies. If you're not certain the string is at least 8 bytes long, you might prefer to have the output left justified, in which case, insert a minus `-` before the first `*`; as written, the shorter string would be right justified.